# is it possible to send data using socket.io-node just to chosen group of users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, socket.io, protocols

how could I implement chat with different rooms? I don't want .**broadcast()** to send data to all logged in users.i just want to send the data to specific user

Comment: each user is connected using a unique *socket* - so, yes, it is possible

Comment: So how can i send the message to specific user on runtime just like any chatapp we select the person and start chat with them

Comment: yes, that sounds right

Comment: Use "rooms" on the server (see `.join()` and `.leave()`).  Add a set of sockets to a room, then socket.io can broadcast just to the sockets in that room.

Answer (score 0):

I've just completed doing something very similar with a game.
I maintain a list of all socket objects with the socket ID as the key. This allows me to emit a message at any time to one particular user.

On registering:

```
var sockets = [];
sockets[socket.id] = socket;
```

To emit:

```
// pass in needed socket ID from client
sockets[socketID].emit('message-name', message);
```

If you have specific questions share your code and I'll help as much as I can.

Comment: No need to keep your own list of sockets.  socket.io already has a list of sockets you can access and adding sockets to a room generates another list for you.

Comment: //this code is working o the server side
// Socket setup & pass server
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    // Handle chat event
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        // console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

});

Comment: //this code working on client side
// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  socket.emit('chat', {
      message: message.value,
      handle: handle.value
  });
  message.value = "";
});

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message to a group of users, you need to create a room for them & then emit a message. doc: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#joining-and-leaving. Following code snippet might be helpful

The user class used

```
User = {
    constructor(socketID, socket) {
        this.socketID = socketID;
        this.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

subscribe user's socket to the room

```
var users = [user1.socketID, user2.socketID, user3.socketID];
var room = 'room';
users.forEach(function (user) {
    user.socket.join(room);
});
```

Then emit the message in the room

```
io.to(room).emit('messageInRoom', message);
```